# Is every direct sum of subpaces orthogonal?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and let $V_1$ be a subspace of $V$ . Suppose that there exists a subspace $V_2$ of $V$ such that $V$ is the direct sum of $V_1$ and $V_2$:
$$V= V_1 \oplus V_2.$$

Can we find an inner product on $V$ such that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are orthogonal ?

Comment: Sure.  A vector space without an inner product has no notion of angles. It can't "tell the difference" between a direct sum and a direct orthogonal sum. So, we can just define our inner product to make them orthogonal (as Jamie does below.)

Comment: A variation on this question: can we make any basis orthonormal with the right inner product? A similar technique shows we can: just define your inner product to be the dot product of the coordinate vectors with respect to the given basis.

Comment: Note that the base field is important.  There are vector spaces on which no meaningful concept of an "inner product" exists.  As long as we can define _at least one_ inner product on $V$, there will be one for which $V_1$ and $V_2$ are orthogonal, and this doesn't depend on the dimension of $V$ (though this will possibly depend on the axiom of choice for particularly large $V$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that they are real vector spaces we can. Pick bases $\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_k\}$ for $V_1$ and $\{u_{k+1},u_{k+2},\dots,u_{n}\}$ for $V_2$. Their union is a basis for $V$ and the inner product
$$ \left\langle \sum_1^n a_i u_i, \sum_1^n b_i u_i \right\rangle = \sum_1^n a_ib_i $$
makes them orthogonal.

Comment: Nice ! Thanks @Jamie Radcliffe.